# Why does this python regular expression return the wrong string

Tags: python, regex, crc32

Below I have a piece of code that should replace one string with another but doesnt seem to do  it. I am not a python or regular expression expert, can anyone tell me why this might be going wrong.

```
def ReplaceCRC( file_path ):
    file = open(file_path,'r+');
    file_str = file.read()
    if( file_str <> '' ):
         crc_list        = re.findall(r'_CalcCRC[(]\s*"\w+"\s*[)]', file_str);
         strs_to_crc     = []
         new_crc_list    = []
         if( crc_list ):
              for crc in crc_list:
                   quote_to_crc    = re.search(r'"\w+"', crc);
                   str_to_crc      = re.search(r'\w+', quote_to_crc.group() ).group();
                   final           = hex(CalcCRC( str_to_crc ))[:2]
                   value           = '%08X' % CalcCRC( str_to_crc )
                   final           = final + value.upper()
                   final_crc       = Insert( crc, ', ' + final + ' ', -1)
                   new_crc_list.append( final_crc )
              if( new_crc_list <> [] ):
                   for i in range(len(crc_list)):
                       print crc_list[i]
                       print new_crc_list[i]
                       term = re.compile( crc_list[i] );
                       print term.sub( new_crc_list[i], file_str );
```

This is the file it is operating on:

```
printf( "0x%08X\n", _CalcCRC("THIS_IS_A_CRC") );
printf( "0x%08X\n", _CalcCRC("PATIENT_ZERO") );
```

This is the output

```
_CalcCRC("THIS_IS_A_CRC")
_CalcCRC("THIS_IS_A_CRC", 0x97DFEAC9 )
printf( "0x%08X\n", _CalcCRC("THIS_IS_A_CRC") );
printf( "0x%08X\n", _CalcCRC("PATIENT_ZERO") );

_CalcCRC("PATIENT_ZERO")
_CalcCRC("PATIENT_ZERO", 0x0D691C21 )
printf( "0x%08X\n", _CalcCRC("THIS_IS_A_CRC") );
printf( "0x%08X\n", _CalcCRC("PATIENT_ZERO") );
```

What it should do is find the CRC string, calculate the value and then put a string in its place in the original string. I have been trying a bunch of stuff, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `if( new_crc_list <> [] ):` is so against PEP-8 code style... You should simply use `if new_crc_list:` - also, the common not-equal operator is not `<>` but `!=`

Comment: And I thought Python was always pretty :/

Comment: `if( file_str <> '' ):`  <=>  `if file_str:`

Comment: Could you please boil this down to a minimal working example? For instance, if you make a file containing "foo", can you change it to "bar"?

Comment: I'd prefer a mimimal RUNNABLE piece of code: (1) what is 'Insert()' (2) what is CalcCRC()

Comment: @Joe I'd like you to post an exemple of result you want to obtain. Do you want ``printf( "0x%08X\n", _CalcCRC("PATIENT_ZERO"), 0x0D691C21 );`` -or- ``printf( "0x%08X\\n", _CalcCRC("THIS_IS_A_CRC", 0x98ABAC4B) );`` -or- ``printf( "0x%08X\\n", _CalcCRC(0x98ABAC4B) );`` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not your problem, but these 3 lines are amazing:

```
final           = hex(CalcCRC( str_to_crc ))[:2]
value           = '%08X' % CalcCRC( str_to_crc )
final           = final + value.upper()
```

Assuming CalcCRC returns a non-negative integer (e.g. 12345567890

Line 1 sets `final` to "0x" irrespective of the input!

```
>>> hex(1234567890)
'0x499602d2'
>>> hex(1234567890)[:2]
'0x'
```

Line 2 repeats the call to CalcCRC!

```
>>> value           = '%08X' % 1234567890
>>> value
'499602D2'
```

Note that `value` is *already* uppercase!

and after line 3, `final` becomes '0x499602D2'

As `value` is not used again, the whole thing can be replaced by

```
final = '0x%08X' % CalcCRC(str_to_crc)
```

**More from Circumlocution City**

These lines:

```
quote_to_crc    = re.search(r'"\w+"', crc);
str_to_crc      = re.search(r'\w+', quote_to_crc.group() ).group();
```

can be replaced by one of:

str_to_crc = re.search(r'"\w+"', crc).group()[1:-1]
str_to_crc = re.search(r'"(\w+)"', crc).group(1)

Comment: Acute eyes. I used this simplification. +1

Answer (score 0):

A quick peek at the real answer:

You need (inter alia) to use re.escape() ....

```
term = re.compile(re.escape(crc_list[i]))
```

and the indentation on your last `if` looks stuffed.

... more after dinner :-)

**Post-prandial update**

You make 3 passes over the whole file, when only one will do the trick. Apart from cutting out an enormous lot of clutter, the main innovation is to use the `re.sub` functionality that allows the replacement to be a function instead of a string.

```
import re
import zlib

def CalcCRC(s):
    # This is an example. It doesn't produce the same CRC as your examples do.
    return zlib.crc32(s) & 0xffffffff

def repl_func(mobj):
    str_to_crc = mobj.group(2)
    print "str_to_crc:", repr(str_to_crc)
    crc = CalcCRC(str_to_crc)
    # If my guess about Insert(s1, s2, n) was wrong,
    # adjust the ollowing statement.
    return '%s"%s", 0x%08X%s' % (mobj.group(1), mobj.group(2), crc, mobj.group(3))

def ReplaceCRC(file_handle):
    regex = re.compile(r'(_CalcCRC[(]\s*)"(\w+)"(\s*[)])')
    for line in file_handle:
        print "line:", repr(line)
        line2 = regex.sub(repl_func, line)
        print "line2:", repr(line2)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys, cStringIO
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    if args:
        f = open(args[0], 'r')
    else:
        f = cStringIO.StringIO(r"""
printf( "0x%08X\n", _CalcCRC("THIS_IS_A_CRC") )
other_stuff()
printf( "0x%08X\n", _CalcCRC("PATIENT_ZERO") )
""")
    ReplaceCRC(f)
```

Result of running script with no args:

```
line: '\n'
line2: '\n'
line: 'printf( "0x%08X\\n", _CalcCRC("THIS_IS_A_CRC") )\n'
str_to_crc: 'THIS_IS_A_CRC'
line2: 'printf( "0x%08X\\n", _CalcCRC("THIS_IS_A_CRC", 0x98ABAC4B) )\n'
line: 'other_stuff()\n'
line2: 'other_stuff()\n'
line: 'printf( "0x%08X\\n", _CalcCRC("PATIENT_ZERO") )\n'
str_to_crc: 'PATIENT_ZERO'
line2: 'printf( "0x%08X\\n", _CalcCRC("PATIENT_ZERO", 0x76BCDA4E) )\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this want you want ? :

```
import re

def ripl(mat):
    return '%s, 0x%08X' % (mat.group(1),CalcCRC(mat.group(2)))

regx = re.compile(r'(_CalcCRC[(]\s*"(\w+)"\s*[)])')


def ReplaceCRC( file_path, regx = regx, ripl = ripl ):
    with open(file_path,'r+') as f:
        file_str = f.read()
        print file_str,'\n'
        if file_str:
             file_str = regx.sub(ripl,file_str)
             print file_str
             f.seek(0,0)
             f.write(file_str) 
             f.truncate()
```

### EDIT

I had forgot the instruction `f.truncate()` , very important, otherwise it remains a tail if the rewritten content is shorter than the initial content

.

### EDIT 2

John Machin,

There is no mistake, my above solution is right, it gives

```
printf( "0x%08X\n", _CalcCRC("THIS_IS_A_CRC"), 0x97DFEAC9 ); 
printf( "0x%08X\n", _CalcCRC("PATIENT_ZERO"), 0x0D691C21 );
```

I hadn't changed it since your comment. I think that I first posted a solution that was incorrect (because I performed some various tests to verify some behaviors and, you know, I sometimes do mix-up with my files and codes), then you copied this incorrect code to try it, then I realized that there was a mistake and corrected the code, and then you posted your comment without noticing I had corrected. I imagine no other cause of such a confusion.

By the way, to obtain the same result, there's even no need of two groups in the pattern defining **regx**, one alone is sufficient. These following `regx` and `ripl()` work as well:

```
regx = re.compile(r'_CalcCRC\(\s*"(\w+)"\s*\)')
# I prefer '\(' to '[(]', and same for '\)' instead of '[)]'

def ripl(mat):
    return '%s, 0x%08X' % (mat.group(),CalcCRC(mat.group(1)))
```

But an uncertainty remains. Each of our result is wise, relativelay to the inaccurate wording of Joe. So, what does he want as precise result ? : must the value **0x97DFEAC9**  be inserted in `CalcCRC("THIS_IS_A_CRC")` as in your result, or after `CalcCRC("THIS_IS_A_CRC")` as in mine ?

To say all, I did like you to obtain a code that could be run: I defined a function **CalcCRC()** of my own consisting simply in `if x=="THIS_IS_A_CRC":  return 0x97DFEAC9` and `if x=="PATIENT_ZERO":  return 0x0D691C21`; I picked these  associations out by seeing the results desired by Joe exposed in his question.

Now , concerning your nasty affirmation that my *"point about redefinition of functions is utter nonsense"*, I think I didn't explain enough what I mean. Putting the regex **regx** and the function **ripl()** as default arguments to the parameters of the function **ReplaceCRC()** has a consequence : the objects **regx** and **ripl()** are created only one time, at the moment the definition of function **ReplaceCRC()** is executed. So, in case that **ReplaceCRC()** will be applied several times in an execution, there will be no re-creation of these objects. I don't know if the function **ReplaceCRC()** is really called several times during the execution of Joe's program, but I think it's a good practice to put this feature in a code in case it may be useful. Maybe, I should have underlined this point in my answer instead of a comment to justify my code relatively to yours. But I try to limit my tendency to write sometimes answers long too much.

Are the points clarified and your annoyance soothed by these explanations ?

Comment: @eyquem: I'm curious: apart from the no-seat-belts in-situ file replacement, what improvement over my answer are you offering?

Comment: @John Machin Well, after having found my solution , I saw yours and I thought "oh he has already done it". However I posted my solution, because it is better. In your solution the pattern defines 3 groups instead of 2 in mine, and the object returned by your **repl_func()** function needs a 4 elements tuple for formating instead of 2 in my **ripl()** function. Moreover I pass the replacement function and the regex as default argument to the **ReplaceCRC()** function: that avoids the redefinition of them each time the **ReplaceCRC()** function is called .

Comment: @John Machin Additionally , there is no need of keyword **return** at the end of **ReplaceCRC()** and you spoil the readibility with use of **StringIO()** option. And still, my solution doesn't have several **prints**, if the reader want to track the execution, he will add them at his convenience.

Comment: @John Machin Concerning the no-seat-belt replacement, I wrote this in-situ replacement because I noticed that the questioner opens the file in 'r+' mode and I suppose that he is aware of what he does. I have no intention to cover extra problems outside the initial questions if that gives too much work , that may also be useless. In the past, I was warning a questioner about all potential problems, that was a too heavy task. I consider that a coder must experience himself the issues to acquire a real knowledge of Python or any other programming language.

Comment: @eyquem: I define 3 groups to avoid your mistake of omitting some of the OP's desired output. Mine: `'printf( "0x%08X\\n", _CalcCRC("THIS_IS_A_CRC", 0x98ABAC4B) )\n'`; yours: `'printf( "0x%08X\\n", _CalcCRC(, 0x98ABAC4B )\n'`. Your point about redefinition of functions is utter nonsense. The functions are defined (in global scope) only once. `ReplaceCRC` is called only once in the script. The difference is a global reference instead of a local reference each time `regex.sub` is called. The StringIO and the prints are there to demonstrate that my solution actually works; yours?

Comment: @eyquem: Your supposition that the OP is aware of what he does can scarcely be founded on reading his code :-)

Comment: Yeah....no idea what I was doing. Lol. I am a C/C++ guy. I did this as a kinda side project trying to experiment. Its really just supposed to be a script to run on files as a pre build step in vc++. I appreciate all the help from both you guys though. But yes...My python is terrible because I am not a python guy at all. The intent was to replace the crc macro in a file with the crc macro plus the actual crc value. So the replacement was to be made in the file.